# $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta\in\mathbb{R},\forall x\in\mathbb{R}(|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon)$ is false?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, first-order-logic

Let the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be discontinuous at c.
Then the statement: $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta\in\mathbb{R},\forall x\in\mathbb{R}(|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon)$ is false.
The negation of the statement: $\exists\epsilon>0,\forall\delta\in\mathbb{R},\exists x\in\mathbb{R}(|x-c|<\delta\;and\;|f(x)-f(c)|\geqslant\epsilon)$ is false because whenever $\delta$ is negative, $|x-c|<\delta$ is false. Is anything wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original statement is meant to express "continuity at $c$", but it's not written precisely enough! In fact, the original statement you gave is *true*, because you can pick $\delta = 0$, regardless of the value of $\epsilon$.

Here's the corrected version of the original statement:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0 \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R} (\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert < \epsilon)$$

This statement is actually false (by definition), assuming that $f$ is not continuous at $c$. The negation is

$$\exists \epsilon > 0 \; \forall \delta > 0 \; \exists x \in \mathbb{R} (\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta ~\text{and}~ \lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert \geq \epsilon)$$

This statement is actually true.

Comment: Yes I change $\delta>0$ to $\delta\in R$ on purpose so that I can create some contradiction. But I prejudge that the first statement is false, so I'm wrong. Thank you!